# Hide "Quantity" label from quantity input field in Woocommerce

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

I just used a piece of code in my functions.php file to hide the quantity box - the code is:

```
//function custom_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {return true;}
//add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually','custom_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Now, when I comment it out, The quantity comes back, but with the "Quantity" label, which it never had before.

Why does this suddenly happen and how do I hide the label?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated html output for this quantity field should be something like:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5c5856feb38cb">Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5c5856feb38cb" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="35" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" aria-labelledby="Happy Ninja quantity">
</div>
```

So the `<label>` tag for this quantity field uses `screen-reader-text` class to hide it with the following CSS rule:

```
.screen-reader-text {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

So you have made some changes somewhere, that's why the "Quantity" label is visible.

---

**Edit:**

So you could try to add the following CSS rule to your active theme's styles.css file:

```
.single-product div.quantity > label {
    display: block !important;
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

It should work and hide the "Quantity" label on single product pages…

Comment: Okay thanks..  so what do I need to add to hide it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry. I totally missed that question. I have some serious issues with my checkout fields that I can't seem to fix :( Thanks for your answer. Please use this link to see the issue here - I just want to hide the "quantity" label - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product/eternal-delight/

Comment: @Michelle I have updated my answer… Try that, it should hide this "Quantity" label…